# Jmeter run all thread groups after one thread group(token generation) exection

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

I am (new to) doing API performance testing in Jmeter, and I have a Token Generation thread group that needs to be ran before all other thread groups(A,B,C). However I also want A B and C thread groups to be ran simultaneously. So how I want it to be executed is:

1. Token Generation
2. A & B & C

I am aware that checking the Run Thread Groups consecutively on Test Plan will allow me to run Token Generation first(as I placed it as the first thread group in the list), however it would executed is:

1. Token Generation
2. A
3. B
4. C

any help& hints are appreaciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special thread group called [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group), as per documentation:

> A special type of ThreadGroup that can be utilized to perform Pre-Test Actions. The behavior of these threads is exactly like a normal Thread Group element. The difference is that these type of threads execute **before the test proceeds to the executing of regular Thread Groups**.

so replace your "Token Generation" Thread Group with the setUp Thread Group and this way the token will be generated before normal testing threads start.

More information: [How to Use the SetUp Thread Group in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)

Comment: got it, thank you! it did work as the first request of A & B were sent at the same start time